# How to make outbound calls with dialogflow es bot via twilio gateway

Tags: python, twilio, dialogflow-es, twilio-twiml

I am trying to create a bot that will make calls by a predefined list of phone numbers and obtain some details from humans on the other side of the lines.
This is my first more or less complex project on python

I added dialogflow ex add-on to twilio
testen outbound calls with samples of text to speech from twilio. And can't figure out how to add dialogflow es bot in to these calls.

Please, help...

And where to get the link that I have to put here?

```
connect = Connect(action='https://myactionurl.com/virtualagent_ended')
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Have you checked out [this Dialogflow ES bot tutorial in Python](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/detect-intent-tts#detect-intent-tts-python)?

You should get that URL to connect your Voice code to the bot when you deploy your app to AppEngine and then point your Incoming Webhook to your AppEngine instance. More info on that in this [Twilio Media Streams dialogflow-integration GitHub project README](https://github.com/twilio/media-streams/tree/master/node/dialogflow-integration).

Comment: Thank you, I found tons of docs that did not help, this one is very straightforward, problem almost solved. I was able to create bot for inbound calls. but how to use it for outbound calls?